# C++ : Utilidad de función strcpy()

Tags: c++

la funcion strcpy() sirve para guardar un string de una variable en otra variable, pero cual seria la diferencia con hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    string var = "Hola mundo";
    string var2 = "";

    var2 = var;
    cout<<var2;

    cout<<endl;system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Recien estoy aprendiendo c++ y hay algunas cosas que no entiendo, desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu ejemplo estas usando el operador de asignación = para asignar el valor contenido en `var` a `var2` y posteriormente imprimes el valor:

```
string var = "Hola mundo";
string var2 = "";

var2 = var;
cout<<var2;
```

**La diferencia es que la función [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) se usa para asignar un string a un array de caracteres, en este caso no se podría utilizar el operador =**.

Este es un ejemplo usando [**strcpy()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) :

```
char mensaje[12];

//Asigna string a Array.
strcpy( mensaje, "Hola mundo");

//Imprime los 4 primeros elementos contenidos en el array.
cout<<mensaje[0]<<mensaje[1]<<mensaje[2]<<mensaje[3];
```

salida:

```
hola
```

Answer (score 1):

La función [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) pertenece a las cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y no debe ser usado en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) salvo en contadas y excepcionales ocasiones. Dicha función, no trabaja con objetos cadena de caracteres (`std::string`) si no con punteros a formaciones de caracteres (`char *`); en C++ moderno el uso de punteros está desaconsejado.

Por lo tanto, estas comparando cosas distintas y la comparación no tiene sentido. La utilidad de función `strcpy()` es la listada en su [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

> ```
> char *strcpy( char *dest, const char *src );
> ```
>
> Copia la cadena de bytes terminada en nulo apuntada por `str`, incluyendo el terminador nulo, a la formación de caracteres cuyo primer elemento está apuntado por `dest`.